# subtracting two specifics row in multiple columns and the result as a new row

Tags: r

suppose I have following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("index" = c(1,2,3,4,5,"total"),"age"=c (10,20,30,40,"non",18) ,"1"=c(1,4,5,6,7,9),"2"=c(8,9,5,6,11,13))
```

I want to subtract row 6 from row 5 in column`X1` and `X2` and then add the result as a new row. my expected output whold be like this:

```
  index age X1 X2
     1  10  1  8
     2  20  4  9
     3  30  5  5
     4  40  6  6
     5 non  7 11
 total  18  9 13
     0   0  2  2
```

I tried following codes but got erros:

```
num_cols <- ncol(df)
df_result <- data.frame()
for (col in 1:num_cols) {
  if (col == 1 || col == 2) {
  
    df_result[, col] <- df[, col]
  } else {
  row
    new_row <- df[5, ]
    new_row[col] <- df[5, col] - df[6, col]
    df_result <- rbind(df_result, new_row)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new row by assignment with `[`. `df[x, 3:4]`  select the `x`th row and the 3rd and 4th column. `-` is vectorized, so not for a `for` loop. With `<-` you can assign the new values to a new row. Empty columns are filled with `NA`s.

```r
df[7, 3:4] <- df[6, 3:4] - df[5, 3:4]

#   index  age X1 X2
# 1     1   10  1  8
# 2     2   20  4  9
# 3     3   30  5  5
# 4     4   40  6  6
# 5     5  non  7 11
# 6 total   18  9 13
# 7  <NA> <NA>  2  2
```